# Imports: Should you, Shouldn't you, syntax and best practices

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, import

Just wondering what the recommended practice is for importing namespaces. Are you always better importing the namespace like the fisrt snippet of code, or are you better to type the full namespace inline with your code.

I like both methods; the first is tidier and takes less code, the second can identify exactly where your accessing some logic from which can provide some clarity when looking over the code. Just wondering if there are pros/cons for either or if this is just a personal preference, currently I use a combination but would like to keep consistant.

```
Imports Core.Tech
Public SomeClass
  Public Function New()
    Return TechMethods.SomeTechFunction()
  End Function
End Class


Public SomeClass
  Public Function New()
    Return Core.Tech.TechMethods.SomeTechFunction()
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Not really a good question for SO.  Everyone has their own opinion, use what makes the most sense to you personally.

Comment: Fair enough... just curious if there were pros n cons to either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a matter of style but the predominant pattern in .Net is to leverage `Import` statements.  Not using an `Import` statement causes unnecessary verbosity in your code.  Especially when you consider the extremely long names of some .Net namespaces.

For example

```
Dim map As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of System.Int32, System.String)
' vs ... 
Dim map As New Dictionary(Of Int32, String)
```

As I mentioned this is mostly a matter of style but there are some cases where it matters.  Most importantly is the use of extension methods.  The usefulness of this feature is severely limited if you don't use any `Import` statements because it will restrict it to extension methods defined in the current namespace (goodbye LINQ).

Comment: Thanks... it was more with regards to referencing my own projects. Especially when referencing multiple projects you can instantly tell which classes come from which project using the more verbose method. However, there's something about typing out the full namespace that just feels wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Another consideration you should make when it comes to `Imports` is if there will be multiple classes (or both methods and classes) with the same name.

For instance, there are three different timers in the `System.Timers`, `System.Threading`, and `System.Windows.Forms` namespaces. If you wanted to use one of the first two timers in a WinForms application, you would want to explicitly mention the namespace or create an alias.

```
'without imports
Dim timer As System.Threading.Timer

'imports
Imports System
Dim timer As Threading.Timer

'alias
Imports ThreadingTimer = System.Threading.Timer
Dim timer As ThreadingTimer
```